# Multiple images upload in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have to upload multiple images into MySQL, but this code can not get the proper output. How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
$target_folder = "../tour-images/";
if ($_FILES['photo_url']['name']) {
    //echo "hii";
    $allowable_extensions = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/png", "image/gif");
    $imagename = $_FILES["photo_url"]["name"];
    //echo "<br>hii".$imagename."<br>".$allowable_extensions;
    $file_type = $_FILES["photo_url"]["type"];
    print_r($file_type);

    if (in_array($file_type, $allowable_extensions)) {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
            //$file_ext = substr($file_type, 6);
            $file_ext = explode('.', $file_type[$i]);
            echo $file_ext;
            $source = $_FILES["photo_url"]['tmp_name'];
            $target1 = $target_folder . $imagename . "." . $file_ext;
            echo "<br>" . $target1;
            $photourl = $target_folder . $imagename . "." . $file_ext;
            echo "hcxxxxxxx" . $photourl;

            if (move_uploaded_file($source, $target1))
            {
                $filename11 = $target1;
            }
        }
    }
} 
else {
    $filename = $target_folder . "noLogo.jpeg";
    $photourl = "noLogo.jpeg";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO image_details(tour_id,photo_url) VALUES('".$id."', '".$filename11."')";
mysql_query($sql);

echo $sql;
```

Comment: What exactly is the correct output? And what is the input you are dealing with?

Comment: i want the upload two or more images upload at a time into the database and i deal with input mutiple images at a time

Comment: For what I can understand, you are only checking one file input, and not two, or the name from the file is an array, which we cannot know, but we guess it's

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Multiple images upload in PHP - more than 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068217/multiple-images-upload-in-php-more-than-5)*.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to upload multiple files and store in the database.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="Filename">
            <input type="file" name="photo_url[]" multiple>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>

        <?php
            if (isset($_FILES['photo_url'])) {
                $images = array();
                $myFile = $_FILES['photo_url'];
                $fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);
                $Filename=$_POST['Filename'];
                $structure = "Uploads/SystemConfiguration/$Filename";

                if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true))
                {
                    die('Failed to create folders...');
                }

                for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
                    $name = $_FILES["photo_url"]["name"][$i];
                    $tmp_name=$_FILES["photo_url"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$structure/$name");
                    $images[] = "$structure/$name";
                }
            }
            $all_images = implode(",",$images);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>

$sql = "INSERT INTO image_details(tour_id,photo_url) VALUES('".$id."','".$all_images."')";
mysql_query($sql);
echo $sql;
```

Comment: i want to only upload image file into database